# Error on trying to configure RavenDB in IIS mode

Tags: iis, web-config, iis-7.5, ravendb, ravendb-studio

Following [the steps in this tutorial](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/deployment/as-iis-application), the first item of "Setting up with IIS 7.5" after clicking on "Modules" in inetmgr, the following error occurs:

[image: Modules error]

> Full image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCM4s.png

### Web.config in RavenDB

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Raven/DataDir" value="~\Data"/>
        <add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="Get"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="All" path="*" verb="*" type="Raven.Web.ForwardToRavenRespondersFactory, Raven.Web"/>
        </handlers>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="Analyzers"/>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

### applicationHost.config

http://pastebin.com/UJTJfB9f

### Try

For a few attempts, I tried to change

this..

```
<section name="modules" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

to this..

```
<section name="modules" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

### Results

When trying to access "in inetmgr Modules worked!"

**However** RavenDB Studio does not work.
The following image:

[image: Error RavenDB Studio]

---

```
Config Error
   This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".  

Config File
   \\?\C:\Users\Riderman\RavenDB-Build-960\Web\web.config
```

Comment: Check the application pool for that application and see if it is in .NET 4.0 mode (just open its properties dialog).

I assume it's in 2.0, hence the error.

Comment: No! Is set to 4.0!  
See...  
http://i.imgur.com/jNaL7.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your server web.config and change `overrideModeDefault` from `Deny` to `Allow`.

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
    <section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Deny" /> 
    <section name="modules" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

You can also manage sections on web server level (just select the Server in the left pane) in your IIS management console and then select "Feature Delegation":

[image]

As you see in the picture above all the features are Read/Write. Currently on my machine the Modules feature is Read Only, so I'd need to change it to Read/Write - in the right hand pane in Set Feature Delegation just click on Read/Write...

Comment: What a crazy thing: today I just searched Google for this very problem and got here at an answer I provided 1 month ago. I'm helping other and MYSELF for future problems... I believe in God's ways and this proves my belief. :) See: when you help others you're doing good to yourself because we're 1 in Christ Jesus.

Comment: :) Very nice story! This answer saved my day also. +1!